# I am making a game and this is my code, but I have issues Error Code #CS1955

Tags: c#

I am making a game, but I am getting issues with the lines:
Their error codes are both CS1955.

```
StartCoroutine(StartSpawning());
```

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
   public Transform[] spawnPoints;
   public GameObject pumpkin;

   void Start () {
       StartCoroutine(StartSpawning());

    }

    IEnumerator StartSpawning
    {
        get
        {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, 3.5f));
                Instantiate(pumpkin, spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, 
                spawnPoints.Length)].position,
                Quaternion.identity);

                StartCoroutine(StartSpawning());
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you would tell us what `CS1955` actually means? Not everybody knows all compiler error codes by number...

Comment: Can't you read?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1955

Comment: yield return /followed/ by some code doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: That said, `StartSpawning` is a read-only private property of `Spawner`, so it makes no sense to call it as if it where a method.

Comment: @Neil: That's absolutely fine. This is an iterator block.

Comment: So how to fix this?

Comment: Basically, you need to change `StartSpawning` to be a method.

Comment: Fixed, I just removed the parathasis. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

```
StartCoroutine(StartSpawning());
```

StartSpawning is a property, but () makes it look like you are calling it like a function.

Change to

```
StartCoroutine(StartSpawning);
```